# Is it possible to mock the window.location object for a qUnit test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, query-string, qunit

Let's say I have a utility function that, for simplicity's sake (the real thing is complicated and irrelevant), returns the current window's querystring.

```
var someUtilityFunction = () {
    return window.location.search.substring(1);
};
```

Now I want to unit test this function in qUnit (not sure if the testing harness is relevant or not):

```
test('#1 someUtilityFunction works', function () {
    // setup
    var oldQS = window.location.search;
    window.location.search = '?key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3';

    var expectedOutput = 'key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3';

    // test
    equals(someUtilityFunction(),
        expectedOutput,
        'someUtilityFunction works as expected.');

    // teardown
    window.location.search = oldQS;
});
```

The problem here is that setting the `window.location.search` to a different querystring is causing the page to reload, essentially entering an infinite request loop. Is there any way to mock out the window.location object **without** making any changes to the `someUtilityFunction` function?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We run into the same problem a few days ago. Mainly there are 2 approaches:

### Rewrite your code

This might not be the best (if any) solution, but consider passing the `window` object to your function to make mocking easier. Even better, use a closure and encapsulate your code. This has a few more advantages:

- You can shadow global vars
- You can use private local vars
- You can avoid naming collisions
- The shadowing makes mocking really easy, just pass in something else

### Wrap your code

You can wrap all your code inside a function which mocks the window object into a local variable. You have basically two possibilities there as well:

Suppose this is the mock:

```
var customWindow = {
    location: {
        search: "",
        hash: ""
    }
};
```

#### Use a closure

```
var someUtilityFunction;

(function(window) {
    // window is now shadowed by your local variable
    someUtilityFunction = () {
        return window.location.search.substring(1);
    };
})(customWindow);
```

This shadows the global `window` with a local `window`.

#### Use the `with` statement

Although I am usually strongly against with, it could really solve a lot of problems here. Since it basically remaps your scope, you can very easily mock your environment.

```
// first some more preparation for our mock
customWindow.window = customWindow;

with(customWindow) {

    // this still creates the var in the global scope
    var someUtilityFunction = () {
        // window is a property of customWindow
        return window.location.search.substring(1);
    };

    // since customWindow is our scope now
    // this will work also
    someUtilityFunction = () {
        // location is a property of customWindow too
        return location.search.substring(1);
    };

}
```

By the way: I don't know if the `search` property suffers from the same symptoms as the `hash` property - namely sometimes including the question mark and sometimes not. But you might want to consider using

```
window.location.search.replace(/^\?/, "");
```

instead of

```
window.location.substr(1);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. rewriting the code would not help as it takes the `window` object optionally - this case is testing when one is not passed. wrapping the function in a "mock block" would be changing the code in the function, which it looks like i may have to do.

Comment: You somehow need to wrap your code in order to avoid rewriting your code. I just tried a `with` wrapper which works well too (however wrong it feels using it). You can then make your custom `window` object globally available to mock your properties and have it available within your code and also from the test as well. I suppose that's how jQuery and Zepto do it as well since they pass `window` and `document` to their wrappers too.

Answer (score 3):

I've had some success using `window.history.pushState`. See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page). For each unit test, I call a function `setQueryString('var=something')` which I then implement like this:

```
function setQueryString(queryString) {
  window.history.pushState({}, '', '?' + queryString);
}
```

You'll need to clear the query string with the `afterEach` method of QUnit.module, otherwise you're query string will be set to the value of the final test, and you'll get weird results.

Comment: Does not work for me. if I do a ``window.history.pushState(...);`` and check it directly with ``console.log(window.location)`` it gives me the current URL of the Qunit-html page. Do you have an Example code?